# MyFrame cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I'm beginning to learn Java but I'm programming for almost six years with c, python, assembly, c++ and I've a problem with this example. I found that gives me this error in Eclipse:

```
MyFrame cannot be resolved to a variable
```

this is the example code:

### `MyFrame`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JButton one=new JButton("1");
    JButton two=new JButton("2");
    JButton tree=new JButton("3");
    JButton four=new JButton("4");
    JButton five = new JButton("5");
    public MyFrame() {
        super("FlowÃLayout");
        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        c.add(one);
        c.add(two);
        c.add(tree);
        c.add(four);
        c.add(five);
        setSize(300,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### `Application`

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* THAT IS THE ERROR */ MyFrame = new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `super("FlowÃLayout");` should be `super(new FlowLayout());` 2) `setSize(300,100);` would best be `pack()` 3) Better not to extend frame in this case, just use an instance of one. 4) If this is typical of the examples in whatever course/tutorial you are studying, find a new source of examples.  I suggest **the** [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
MyFrame = new MyFrame();
```

to

```
new MyFrame();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the variable

```
MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
```

answering as a community wiki since this is very basic java knowledge, and the question should be closed as a typo error.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `main()` method, you have this line:

```
MyFrame = new MyFrame();
```

The above line should instead be

```
MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
```

Since you are not using the variable anywhere else in the program, you could as well use

```
new MyFrame();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe I have to put MyFrame in another java class?